# CSS media to hide/show div in mobile and desktop?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have this **real code** to show and hide two divs depending on device type:

**Problem**: in Android the #div-desktop is shown.

- I need to show only div#div-mobile on mobile devices
- I need to show only div#div-desktop on desktop devices

CSS

```
        @media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 700px) {
      #div-mobile {    display: block;  }
      #div-desktop {    display: none;  }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 3000px) {
      #div-mobile {    display: none;  }
      #div-desktop {    display: block;  }

}
```

HTML

```
<div id="div-mobile">m<img width="100%" height="auto" src="http://uggafood.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/ugga-food_mobile.jpg" alt="" width="600" height="1067" /></div>


<div id="div-desktop">d<img width="100%" height="auto"  src="http://uggafood.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/ugga-food_desktop.jpg" alt="" width="1920" height="1280" /></div>
```

Comment: Is it truly necessary you detect device TYPE and not just screen size?

Comment: @mayersdesign ok, how do I detect the device?

Comment: are you checking this on android device?

Comment: @SahilDhir yes, problem is only in Android device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just checked the live link.

**Meta tag is missing for responsive devices.**

Add the below code for detecting mobile devices.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Adding this really zoomed in my mobile site, by double or triple. Anyone else having this issue?

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**
After seeing your site, you need to add:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

---

You can just use `min-width`

Also, don't use `width/height` html tags in `img` use CSS instead

---

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%
}

#div-desktop {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 701px) {
  #div-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
  #div-desktop {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div-mobile">m<img src="http://uggafood.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/ugga-food_mobile.jpg" alt="" /></div>
<div id="div-desktop">d<img src="http://uggafood.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/ugga-food_desktop.jpg" alt="" /></div>
```

Comment: Not working in Android device. Same problem: only  '#div-desktop' is shown. You can check it here http://uggafood.com/

Comment: This did the trick: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: You can omit that @media screen and (max-width: 700px){ ... } and do mobile-first approach

Answer (score 2):

Change your [media queries](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) to the following.

Just change the widths to whatever you'd like. The top media query says if the min width is above standard mobile sizes show `xyz`, then the second one says if it's below do `abc`.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {

    #div-mobile { display: none; }
    #div-desktop { display: block; }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

    #div-mobile { display: block; }
    #div-desktop { display: none; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

this line only find the size resolution of the user system and gives to your css code
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Answer (score 0):

If you use sass, this is a very efficient way of effecting media queries and writing appropriate css per devise: https://eduardoboucas.github.io/include-media

> include-media is a Sass library for writing CSS media queries in an easy and maintainable way, using a natural and simplistic syntax.

Comment: Kindly add context to any links so your Answer is self contained, meaning the answer needs to be here in the Answer itself. See ["Provide context for links"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It would be preferable if you could answer the Question in your own words here and link only as a reference. How does it work? How is it used? Please show how it answers the Question.